# GNU Info like pdf reader

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, info

Is there a PDF reader in the Ubuntu repository (or elsewhere) which can navigate through sections of an e-book like “GNU Info” does through nodes?

It should support shortcuts which info has, like <kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd> to navigate between sections, <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> to navigate between subsections and so on…

Comment: The default PDF reader (Evince) supports listing sections of a PDF (if they're defined). In the sidepane, switch from *Thumbnails* to *Index*.

Comment: @muru I meant navigation using the shortcuts which info has, like using n to go to the next node, p to the previous node and so on...

Comment: then you should edit your question to make that clear.

Comment: Pretty much all GTK+ applications have mnemonics for most user actions that you can tie to arbitrary key sequences. So I guess Evince does too. It's just not very convenient or easy to write a configuration file for that…

Comment: @David So, evince has "user actions" which can do the things mentioned in the question?

Comment: No, sorry. Not that I know of. My earlier statement was indeed mistaken and misleading. I mainly meant to say that you can create keyboard shortcuts if you find a GTK+ application that already lets you do this stuff through menus or toolbars.

Comment: In Evince you can navigate between sections and sub-sections using the arrows keys. The same is possible in Okular. However, this is only possible if the document itself defines the section nodes; if not there is no way for the reading software to guess them.